# CSS or JS animated loader controlled by percent of something (like percent of file loaded)

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animated loader that is tied to the progress of another variable. In my case it's percent of an uploaded file completed, so it really just needs to follow a variable from 0% to 100% which I can simulate for the time being. However, all the CSS loader animations I can find control the animation using keyframes for the style of animation I'm using. It *has* to be a circular loader, not a bar or anything else.

So the first problem really is whether or not a CSS based loader can be controlled by an external variable, like a setInterval that counts from 0 to 100, and gets translated to a % of a degree, and then gives that to the animation.

I'm thinking this is not possible in a CSS based animation because of how keyframes work.

What might be another solution / approach?

Comment: Loaders built using CSS can be controlled. Search for loaders built using SVG.
SVG tag is the solution for you problem. It might be little bit complex but there are samples on internet you can use.

Comment: I found a partial solution that outlines how to animate based on an external variable. Basically, you don't need the animate CSS class, or @keyframes. Instead you just tie the incrementing variable directly to a css "transform: deg({theCounter})". This link shows the (at)keyframe approach and then explains the secondary approach but doesn't have code for it: https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/circular-progress-css/